# Alfresco : Cannot find Alfresco Repository

Tags: postgresql, solr, alfresco

I am new with Alfresco Community, i have trouble when i tried to configure database. i follow the step from here but it's not working i still got an error : Cannot find Alfresco Repository on this server. (Does this application have access to alfresco-global.properties? Does this application have cross-context permissions?)

```
here is alfresco-global

###############################
## Common Alfresco Properties #
###############################

dir.root=C:/Alfresco/alf_data

alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=127.0.0.1
alfresco.port=8088
alfresco.protocol=http

share.context=share
share.host=127.0.0.1
share.port=8088
share.protocol=http

### database connection properties ###
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.username=alfresco
db.password=testinsa
db.name=alfresco

db.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.20.0.71:5433/${db.name}
# Note: your database must also be able to accept at least this many connections.  Please see your database documentation for instructions on how to configure this.
db.port=5433
db.pool.max=275
db.pool.validate.query=SELECT 1

# The server mode. Set value here
# UNKNOWN | TEST | BACKUP | PRODUCTION
system.serverMode=UNKNOWN

### FTP Server Configuration ###
ftp.port=21

### RMI registry port for JMX ###
alfresco.rmi.services.port=50500

### External executable locations ###
ooo.exe=C:/ALFRES~1/LIBREO~1/App/libreoffice/program/soffice.exe
ooo.enabled=true
ooo.port=8100
img.root=C:\\alfresco-community\\imagemagick
img.coders=${img.root}\\modules\\coders
img.config=${img.root}
img.gslib=${img.root}\\lib
img.exe=${img.root}\\convert.exe

jodconverter.enabled=false
jodconverter.officeHome=C:/ALFRES~1/LIBREO~1/App/libreoffice
jodconverter.portNumbers=8100

### Initial admin password ###
alfresco_user_store.adminpassword=e32bca6e6d84b73a6278c84bff8242df

### E-mail site invitation setting ###
notification.email.siteinvite=false

### License location ###
dir.license.external=C:/ALFRES~1

### Solr indexing ###
index.subsystem.name=solr4
dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
solr.host=localhost
solr.port.ssl=@@BITROCK_SOLR_SSL_PORT@@

### Allow extended ResultSet processing
security.anyDenyDenies=false

### Smart Folders Config Properties ###
smart.folders.enabled=false

### Remote JMX (Default: disabled) ###
alfresco.jmx.connector.enabled=false
```

Comment: have you created maven project or you have installed alfresco?

Comment: no not yet how can i create that ? #Krutik Jayswal

Comment: I think you have create that project using alfresco installation , right? once delete the extracted alfresco and share  folder from alfresco-home\tomcat\webapps and then try.

Comment: What do you want to do?
If you want to use and test Alfresco please use the installer: http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/simpleinstalls-community-intro.html
If you want to develop to Alfresco please use the maven sdk:
http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/sdk-getting-started.html
And take a look at Jeff Potts Tutorials :
http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/

Answer (score 2):

The Alfresco installer ships with PostgreSQL. When it is installed it will place the PostgreSQL driver (postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41.jar) in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib.
if this lib is not there then place it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Is your database up and running when you start Alfresco? 
   You can confirm once by using a tool like https://www.pgadmin.org/
2. If the database is up and running, and you are able to use the same credentials to connect to the database as mentioned in the properties file, then try creating a new database and mention the new name in the properties file.

Also, posting a snippet from the stack trace generally helps identify the root cause quicker.

Hope this Helps!
Sid

Answer (score 1):

Looks like alfresco-global.properties is not in the correct location.
 Place your alfresco-global.properties file in

```
<alfresco-home>/tomcat/shared/classes
```